# FOREIGN KEY ... REFERENCE Getting no errors, but just empty columns from database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Auto incrementation seems to work just fine, however it looks like there is something with the primary or foreign keys (maybe?) I don't know since I don't get any error messages.
Here is my code for the database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Album`;
CREATE TABLE `Album` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `album_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `album_thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Album` (`album_name`,`album_thumbnail`)
VALUES
('est','/media/test.jpg'),
('consequatur','/media/test.jpg'),
('cumque','/media/test.jpg'),
('sunt','/media/test.jpg'),
('maiores','/media/test.jpg'),
('enim','/media/test.jpg'),
('voluptatibus','/media/test.jpg'),
('officiis','/media/test.jpg'),
('sapiente','/media/test.jpg'),
('itaque','/media/test.jpg');



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Artist`;
CREATE TABLE `Artist` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `artist_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Artist` (`artist_name`)
VALUES
('Dr. Liza Gleason'),
('Luz Feest'),
('Nigel Beier'),
('Dan Mosciski DDS'),
('Reta Altenwerth'),
('Felipe Runolfsson'),
('Pamela Kessler'),
('Mr. Chester Von PhD'),
('Nayeli Rosenbaum IV'),
('Haven Roberts');



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Track`;
CREATE TABLE `Track` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `track_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `likes` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `track_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Track` (`track_name`,`time`,`likes`,`track_link`)
VALUES
('facere','07:29:26','0','http://heaney.com/'),
('placeat','13:31:39','0','http://mclaughlinschowalter.com/'),
('numquam','11:51:06','0','http://www.reicherthowell.com/'),
('accusantium','13:58:47','0','http://www.white.net/'),
('molestiae','14:22:06','0','http://www.leuschke.info/'),
('dolores','05:33:34','0','http://www.schuppe.com/'),
('natus','18:14:07','0','http://klocko.com/'),
('optio','01:44:57','0','http://hillshoeger.biz/'),
('laudantium','23:41:02','0','http://hartmannmiller.org/'),
('illo','05:18:46','0','http://www.sanford.com/');




DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Album_Track`;
CREATE TABLE `Album_Track` (
  `album_id` int NOT NULL,
  `track_id` int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`) REFERENCES `Album`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`track_id`) REFERENCES `Track`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Artist_Album`;
CREATE TABLE `Artist_Album` (
  `artist_id` int NOT NULL,
  `album_id` int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`) REFERENCES `Artist` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`) REFERENCES `Album` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm getting all table values except for Album_Track and Artist_Album. They stay empty without any errors. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi. You didn't insert into those tables so why do you expect rows to be inserted into them? What do you expect to be inserted & why that? (Non-rhetorical questions.) If you express your question clearly it will be a faq to be googled not asked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the table `Album_Track` the columns `album_id` and `track_id` don't have any default values. If you don't specify them, the `INSERT` query fails.

You need to specify the values of those columns, since MySQL doesn't have any way of guessing them. How could it guess?

There must be error codes or error messages. For some reason, you are not seeing them.

The correct way of inserting is, for example:

```
INSERT INTO Album_Track (album_id, track_id, artist_name)
  VALUES (1, 1, 'Dr. Liza Gleason');
```

This will insert a row properly.

Comment: I tried to make connections to Album.id and Track.id, so that the values from those will be automatically written down in Album_Track 
FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`) REFERENCES `Album`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`track_id`) REFERENCES `Track`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE

Comment: A foreign key enforces the values in the table follow the rules; that is, they are inserted according to the relationship between tables. It does not insert values for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answers so far! But I have still questions... I cleaned the code a bit. So Album_Track and Artist_Album are my two tabes to connect everything together. Album.id, Track.id, Artist.id are generated by using AUTO_INCREMENT. If these values cannot be automatically added to Album_Track and Artist_Album, how is it possible to make sure that the values are still same after adding or deleting rows?

Comment: The `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed value can be recovered after each row insertion. This is used in programming all the time. If you are inserting using a script, then I would recomment to explicitly set them. You can. For example: `INSERT INTO Album (id, album_name, album_thumbnail) VALUES (1, 'est', '/media/test.jpg');`. The `id` column is explicit here. You can keep the `AUTO_INCREMENT` anyway.